# Salesforce authorize an application without browser

Tags: salesforce

Hello guys I am trying to authorize my salesforce android application ,I followed this post https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com
Here I found information regarding authentication but my problem is 
I want to get authorization code through http request ,In the post it said that we are able able to get that when the browser redirected with the code contained in the url. Is it possible to do that in a non-browser application

Answer (score 0):

The [Username and Password Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_a_Token_in_an_Autonomous_Client_.28Username_and_Password_Flow.29) only requires your application to interact with Salesforce servers. You don't need to redirect the users browser.

Of course, you shouldn't be prompting users for their credentials if you can help it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right but the problem is it doesn't give refresh_token

Comment: @Goutam If you have the credentials why to you need the refresh token?

Comment: The template android application uses webview to authenticate.At the end of the authentication there is a json string returned by server which contains a refresh token

Comment: @Goutam The refresh token is only applicable with certain authentication flows, such as the Web Server flow. It is not applicable to the to the username and password flow. If you are making an Android app then you should be using the [User-Agent](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_in_a_Browser_or_Native_Application_.28User-Agent_Flow.29) flow and the embedded browser.

Comment: Is there a way i can get rid of the web view (embedded browser)

Comment: @Goutam Only by switching to one of the flows that don't require it, such as the Username and Password flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71202/discussion-between-goutam-and-daniel-ballinger).

Comment: the same problem - Is there a way to get rid of webview to authorize the app. We also need refresh_token to reauthenticate the user.